# Vertex<>Layout mis-match within PIX(Graphics Debugger)

Tags: directx11

There's more than a screen-full of code to specify the actual vertex data, the inputlayout, and the shader signature...

[image]

**Misleading symptoms:**
Then, it does whatever it wants, anyway.

I can "cause it to rearrange them", but it never puts them in the order it was told to (3 different times/ways). The actual vertex data matches both slot layouts, but is jumbled as soon as I need it; fun.

Edit:
**Please, at least, explain why the left panel doesn't match the right panel.** Trying to make it rearrange them doesn't even produce linear results. I.e. if I move COLOR somewhere else, it moves it, but it could end up anywhere, possibly bumping the offset for WORLD and/or anything else.

Comment: I'm not really even sure what this is asking. What's the context? Further, we don't make the question titles match the answers.

Comment: @Byte56 I drove myself nuts for hours trying to figure this out and nothing was even wrong. Documenting this could save someone else using PIX a lot of time and hair. On the other hand, it's also likely to eventually get patched.

Comment: I'm just saying, I'd say this question is "Unclear what you're asking" close reason. You're not describing the problem or what you're trying to do or what you've already tried to do to fix it.

Comment: @Byte56, specifically, I was trying to debug a new-to-me technology (geometry shader) but ran into this PIX bug in the process. All of the items you mentioned are already provided in the question.

Comment: TBH, with the graphic alone, the question (Why?) is obvious and the answer would answer that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most recent games, the developers clearly spent more time making it pretty than making it good. As of this posting, the panel on the right does not correspond to anything real. The data was always correct and in-place.

[image]